# motor hums, light works, fan won't turn

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I just hung a ceiling fan with light fixture.  I wired black to black and white to white.  The fan and light are operated by a remote.  The light will go on, motor hums, but the fan won't turn.  I have installed many fans before and never had this problem.

Comment: Can you spin the blades by hand?

Comment: Is it possible for you to send us a picture of the fan and cable?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Could be a mechanical problem.  Try this: with the power OFF, try to rotate the fan with your finger. It should spin freely for awhile after you poke it.  If not, then something is mechanically impeding the travel of the fan blades.

Check for anything touching any part of that rotating fan assembly.  Maybe some left-over protective packaging that you missed?  Or a wire that is bent in and pushing on the blades?

If not the above then good chance this is just a defective fan motor.

Comment: Motor, or just a bad capacitor. Sometimes a motor with a defective capacitor will continue turning if you give it a push start.